# What trees are compatible for grafting with cherry trees?

Tags: fruit-trees, grafting, cherries

What varieties of trees are compatible for grafting with cherries other than other cherries? Plum, what else?

Answer (score 6):

IIRC, anything from the ["*Prunus*" family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus), which includes plums, apricots, peaches, nectarines, and almonds as well as cherries.

My personal rootstock preference is for "[Mazzard](http://extension.oregonstate.edu/wasco/sites/default/files/sweet_cherry_rootstocks_pnw619.pdf)" but that may depend on your soil type.

The link I revised the Mazzard mention to point to does note some specific cultivars having issues with specific rootstocks other than Mazzard, which probably means that some other in-family members may not actually work with at least some cultivars. But generally, they all at least could work.

Comment: Ahh you also like grafting nursery stock? I find Mazzard does well in compacted clay, which is why it's what i use 90% of the time. I think some plums can be grafted onto a cherry, but not most other stone fruit. I think plums have the greatest compatibility in that you can graft the other stone fruits to them (and some cherries).